# VBS MailMerge.OpenDataSource as UTF-8

Tags: vba, utf-8, vbscript, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Word template with tags like `<<EXAMPLE>>` that its content is replaced by what is in a text file in UTF-8.

All this is done by a script that works correctly, but I need to be able to open `file2` as UTF-8.

Can anyone help me?

This is the script and the file that I have to open in UTF-8 is the `file2`:

```vb
Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
doc.Visible = False
doc.displayAlerts = False

Set objParameters = WScript.Arguments 

file1 = "TEMPLATE.DOC" 
file2 = "INFO.TXT"
filetmp = "TMP.pdf"
file3 = "FINAL.pdf"

Set wb = doc.Documents.Open(file1)

wb.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(file2)

wb.MailMerge.Destination = 0 'wdSendToNewDocument
wb.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = 1
wb.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = 1
wb.MailMerge.Execute()

doc.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
...
doc.Selection.Find.Execute , , , , , , , , , , 2

doc.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat filetmp, 17 'wdExportFormatPDF

doc.ActiveDocument.Close False
wb.Close False
doc.Quit False    

Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Fso.Movefile filetmp, file3
```

Comment: Does `wb.MailMerge.OpenDataSource file2, 5` help?

Comment: No, it doesn't work...

Comment: If you're using the Microsoft Text ODBC driver, then you might need to create a Schema.ini file with `CharacterSet = UTF-8` in its contents.  For further info, see these links: [Working with Text file data](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/work-with-text-file-data-using-the-microsoft-text-driver-creating-a-csv-data-file.html) and [Schema.ini reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017) Hope this helps.

Comment: No, i'm not using it. Tks

Comment: Please describe the actual *problem* you're having with the file. Some sample content, for example, how it *ought* to appear in the merge result and how it does appear. Word's mail merge is old technology - there's no way to specify character code formats. Most likely, you'll need to open the file in Word, save it as a Word document, then merge to that.

Comment: I want to do:
1.- Menú Mailings - Select Recipients - Use Existing List
2.- I select the file (file2 in the script)
3.- In the new window "Confirm Data source", i check show all and i select "All Word documents"
4.- In the new window "File conversion" i check "another codification" and i select "Unicode (UTF-8).

If I do this manually, it works. But in the script I think I'm missing the end part, to indicate that the coding is UTF-8.

Comment: I have recorded a macro with these steps and it shows me this:
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeOther

Comment: As you can see, nothing from UTF-8 appears. Moreover, if I change the conversion and put another one, the code generated by the macro is the same.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify the registry of the machine running the merge, I suggest you try adding a DWORD entry called DefaultCPG to the registry under the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options (using the appropriate Word version number), and setting its value to decimal 65001 (UTF-8). However, that only has a chance of working if Word is opening the data source using its text converter rather than OLE DB. An alternative is to force Word to use OLE DB using a .odc file, and specify the encoding in a schema.ini as mentioned by @leeharvey1.